# Wifi stops working and needs to be restarted

Tags: networking, wireless

only at the office, my wifi connection stops working after a couple of minutes and needs to be restarted (using `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` or the gnome system menu). 
At home, there is no problem and at the office, no one else has the same problem.

Comment: Inspect the logs with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`. That should give you a hint.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try to :)